# Checking "this" for nullptr - undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, nullptr

Let's consider this piece of code:

```
struct config
{
    int get( )
    {
        if ( this == nullptr ) return 1;
        return value;
    }

    int value = 5;
};

config* c = nullptr;
int result = c->get();
```

This works both in clang and gcc (I think in MSVC too). Is this (running a function on a nullptr pointer) undefined behaviour? If so (or not) where in the C++ standard is this defined as UB or allowed?

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined, even if it's only "conceptual" (i.e. no actual memory access occurs). As far as I can tell, this is only mentioned in a note (section 11.3.2 in C++17): "[...] indirection through a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior."

Comment: @molbdnilo is it ub to call method via pointer , if method does not dereferences this. (call method which is essentualy static, but not declared as one) . I thought in this case pointer via which method is called is just unused parameter and it is irrelevant whether pointer points to valid object or not.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur You can't call a member function on a pointer without dereferencing it - both `*` and `->` dereference the pointer. (Dereferencing does not necessarily involve any memory access, but can be undefined nonetheless.) Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined even if you're calling a static member function; if `get` were static, `c->get()` would be undefined but `config::get()` would be fine.

Comment: Where this comes into play is that the compiler's optimizer can rely on this being the case, so can treat the "impossible" code as a "never can happen" code path and cull it out.